# Hadoop on Mesos uses only one node?

Tags: hadoop, mesos

I have successfully set up Mesos 0.22.1 cluster on 5 nodes. I can run Marathon and Chronos tasks on all slave nodes. Now I’m trying to run Hadoop jobs using Mesos Scheduler. I have followed very good [tutorial](https://strat0sphere.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/hadoop-on-mesos-installation-guide/) and I could run wordcount test job. But when I try to run some larger job (loading data from Kafka to HDFS using Camus) job is running without the errors, but uses only one node with one task tracker, though it has in total 30 map jobs, and my nodes configured to run 2 map jobs in parallel.

What am I missing? Shouldn’t Jobtracker split task to run in parallel on all available nodes using 2 Map slots on eash node?

And what is strange - on Jobtracker webpage cluster summary reports only 1 available node. Is it correct behavior?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you check at the mesos interface mesos_master:5050 how many slave nodes your mesos cluster has?

Comment: It has 5 available slaves and when I use other frameworks (Marathon, Chronos) tasks evenly distributed across all slaves.

Comment: In the Mesos UI, do you see failed TaskTracker executors on the other nodes? Is the URI for `mapred.mesos.executor.uri/name` resolvable from all nodes?

Comment: No, there is no any failed TaskTracker task in UI, also we I run Hadoop multiple times it starts on different nodes, but uses only one node at once.